# Handling one to many relationship in Android Room

Tags: android, android-room

I am new to Android Room persistence library. I am trying to design a School and Student class.

A school can have a list/set of students. There are the queries I want to support.

- Get list of students for a given school id
- Update a student for a given student id
- Delete a student for a given student id

School class:

```
@Entity
public class School {
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "school_id")
    public String schoolId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "school_name")
    public String schoolName;
}
```

Student class:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = School.class,
        parentColumns = "school_id",
        childColumns = "school_id",
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE))
public class Student {
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "student_id")
    public String studentId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "student_name")
    public String studentName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "school_id")
    public String schoolId;
}
```

I am trying to understand how my Dao layer should be written. Here is my attempt at it.

Student Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface StudentDao {
    @Query(SELECT * FROM Student WHERE school_id = :schoolId)
    List<Student> getSudents(String schoolId);

    @Query("DELETE FROM Student WHERE student_id = :studentId")
    void deleteStudent(String studentId);

    @Query("UPDATE Student SET student_name = :newName WHERE student_id = :studentId")
    void updateStudent(String studentId, String newName);
}
```

Is this way of using the Student Dao correct or should I use @Relations instead to support 1:N relationship?

Comment: Mayben you read it before, but here is a good article explaining room relationships: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a

Comment: Yes, I have read the article before. But I am trying to understand the best practice between using foreign keys and relations.

Comment: Also the article talks briefly on the Dao class. That is where my question is. If the way I have my Dao class is good enough or if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Hello. Here you have a article showing the different relations: http://androidkt.com/database-relationships/. And here you have another one here use @Relation annotation https://medium.com/@magdamiu/android-room-persistence-library-relations-75bbe02e8522.